How to describe a project , when project name is itself confidential, in resume?
I am writing my resume to highlight what the project is for and what is my key responsibilities . But I am stuck as I don't know if the project name is confidential for the company, where I am currently working on. For being on the safe side I am assuming it is confidential. I am thinking to slightly change the name of the project but not sure. I am also thinking to mention project name is changed due to confidential.

"I don't know if the project name is confidential for the company" Why don’t you just ask them?

List what is meaningful to the propective employer.

Your specific skillset points that were meaningful to the project
Any leadership roles you had
Meaningful lessons learned (if exemplary)
Just enough about the stack and scope to explain the other points

What is NOT important - project names, specifics that don't relate directly to your skillset.
Show respect for your past / current employer's privacy. To professionals, it demonstrates appropriate proper discretion by not providing internal information.
It is important to convey what you know, learned, and lead, along with how big of a project it was.
Consider the difference:
"Lead a team of 5 vue developers on a rewrite of an app that is used by 2k clients. Learned how to run sprints."
versus
"front end team lead"
People will assume the least/worst. Balance that with using the absolute fewest words in this AI generated world. BTW - I dislike AI generated resumes, but that is MHO.

Nobody cares what your employer happens to call the project you're working on, that's entirely irrelevant to what you can do.
Your resumé should be about you, not your employer.

So I can mention the name of the project.

I don't know what your employer's policies/expectations are. But the point is that it doesn't matter - there's absolutely no need to include the your employer's internal name for a project on your resumé in any case, independent of whether it might be confidental or not - because it conveys zero information to the person reading your resumé.

You can absolutely not mention the name of the project. If the new company finds out that you gave them confidential information, they will assume you will do the same with their confidential information. I wouldn’t hire you. The fact that you need to ask here means I wouldn’t hire you.

There is no reason to mention the name of the product, if it is or maybe confidential. Just mention enough about  the kind of project it is for folks to understand the scale of what you were working on -- whether your design was going into a supercomputer, a laptop, or a toy, for example

@keshlam, thanks for valuable suggestion.

For improvement I'd suggest to make it clear that the project name is irrelevant for OP especially for the reason that the project if secret. If OP could say "lead the Gemini project at Google for 2 years" that would have some impact, because everyone (at least in a similar field) would know about the project. However, in OP's case it is especially the nature of the confidential project that makes it irrelevant or even hurtful to mention it to outsiders, cause nobody knows about project "GammaAlpha8323".

Just say “I was working on a highly confidential project. I used the following tools.. “ If you ask you about the project they either check whether you can be trusted, so you say “sorry, that was confidential”, or they cannot be trusted so you give the same answer.

"I worked on an internal project where I was responsible for XYZ, I made a key contribution where I solved Problem ABC that resulted in the project completing 1 week ahead of schedule"
Calling it Project Nightshade or Project Gordian Knot or Project Snazzy-Name is not going to have any bearing on your prospective employer.
Even if the work is publicly known, the internal project name is unlikely to be public knowledge.
Now, that said - whilst it is unlikely, I would still not refer to it by name - because you dont need to, you can talk around the project.
For example - I had a project that consolidated a number of disparate internal CRM and Billing systems and moved them to a single system that was used by the business.
One of the key challenges was the ETL from the various databases (that used different Database technologies) and turning it into a unified output that could be imported into the target source system.
We solved this by moving it all into a single Database, then running a series of transformation SPs until all the data was in a unified format.
You dont know what the project was called, you dont know what those systems where or the specific technology or anything that might be confidential - you simply know what the problem was and how I went about trying to solve it.
There is nothing specific or that might breach an NDA or confidentiality in that statement.
